# How to stop ngRepeat from repeating data inputted in a textarea?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Here is my Plnkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/69gkIzHUnIl7r6kpvo6L

When I type data in the `textarea` and click "Add," the added `textarea` has data I typed in the first one.

I do not want this. I want the added `textarea` to be blank, but I also want it to be part of ngModel "customize." I want it to be a new instance of `$scope.customize`, just as the first `textarea` is.

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you're using the same `ng-model` for all `textareas`, all you need to do is to use a different `ng-model` value for each one , and then you can read the content of that `textarea` in your `controller` using the `ng-model` you set.

Refer to this [updated version](https://plnkr.co/edit/C4jIG888ySbcL6DI1ZqW?p=preview) of your code.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working plunker example
https://plnkr.co/edit/TSGT04nCV3NK16nsl1e6?p=preview
Now we have item in items which binded to each new textarea

Just make a little change to textarea

```
<textarea rows="5" cols="50" placeholder="Paste data here." ng-model="item.hed"></textarea>
```